# Authorization Header in request is always null

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created a Delegated Handler to do some token authentication.

```
public class SimpleWebTokenHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       if (request.Headers.Authorization == null)
       {
           return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
       }
       return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    } 
}
```

I am not even getting to the token validation part because the Autorization header is always null. However I can see it chrome developer tools it is being sent.

Comment: That's weird, could you show how the Authorization header look like and how is it constructed?

Comment: Turns out that the format of the Authorization header has to be something like <Authorization> <Scheme> <token>="<tokenValue>" and I was missing the quotes

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the format of the Authorization header has to be something like

```
<Authorization> <Scheme> <token>="<tokenValue>"
```

I was missing the quotes.